# Find href in table use Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have html like this :

```
<table class="down_url_table_td_table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center">
                <a href="http://dl121.dix3.com/downfile/nash20160419003/a5dd2131/a7b40b3e?md5=6825a9a1c6c564362e9de51a6efb2249" onclick="setCookie('vid1', 'e4d524c17d912066', 1*60*60*1000);">
            Click here to download</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

How i can convert this to Regex ?

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"Here"
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kX8mY1/1 will work but it is taking too many steps in case of failure..maybe someone will come with an efficient one..also you can use parser for these tasks

Comment: Microsoft has an example that extracts hrefs from HTML using regular expressions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9e807fx(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do what you're attempting to do is to use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

With that nuget package you can use the following code:

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(@"<table class=""down_url_table_td_table"" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = ""center"" >
                            <a href = ""http://dl121.dix3.com/downfile/nash20160419003/a5dd2131/a7b40b3e?md5=6825a9a1c6c564362e9de51a6efb2249"" onclick = ""setCookie('vid1', 'e4d524c17d912066', 1*60*60*1000);"">
                        Click here to download </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr >
                </tbody ></table >");
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var table = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("down_url_table_td_table")).Single();
var href = table.Descendants("a").SingleOrDefault()?.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
<table class="down_url_table_td_table">.*?<a href="([^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT7wD6/1)

**Explanation:**
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)